# i am trying to add user information to firebase createuserwithemailandpassword

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

Whenever I try to add the user data, the wrong uid is being applied to the user data, it is applying the uid from the previous account created even after i have deleted the account from the database.

I read that i must create a child node to add the remaining user credentials which is what I am trying to do. But the current uid from the recieved promise is not being sent to the user database. please help.
[image]
second image
[image]

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import {v4 as uuid} from 'uuid'
import {db} from '../Features/util/firebase'
import {set,ref} from 'firebase/database'
import { getAuth, createUserWithEmailAndPassword } from "firebase/auth";


function Register() {
  const [fname, setFname]=useState('');
  const [lname, setLname]=useState('');
  const [phone, setPhone]=useState('');
  const [email, setEmail]=useState('');
  const [address, setAddress]=useState('');
  const [username, setUsername]=useState('');
  const [password, setPassword]=useState('');
  const [uid, setUid]= useState('');

  const createUser=(e)=>{
    e.preventDefault();    

    const auth = getAuth();

    createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth,email,password)
    .then((userCredential)=>{
      console.log("signed in")
      const user = userCredential.user;
      console.log(user.uid);
      setUid(userCredential.user.uid)
    })
    .then(()=>
    set(ref(db,'users/') , {
     fname:fname,
     lname:lname,
     phone:phone,
     email:email,
     address:address,
     username:username,
     userId:uid,
   }))
    .catch((error)=>{
      const errorCode = error.code;
      const errorMessage = error.message;
      clearFields();
    });

    function clearFields (){
      setAddress('');
      setEmail('');
      setFname('');
      setLname('');
      setPassword('');
      setPhone('');
      setUid('');
      setUsername('');
    }       
  }   
  return (
    <div>
        <form onSubmit={createUser}>
            <label >First Name: </label>
            <input type='text' value={fname} onChange={(e) => setFname(e.target.value)} required/><br/>

            <label >Last Name: </label>
            <input type='text' value={lname} onChange={(e) => setLname(e.target.value)} required ></input><br></br>

            <label > Phone No.: </label>
            <input type='tel' value={phone} onChange={(e) => setPhone(e.target.value)} required></input><br></br>

            <label >e-Mail: </label>
            <input type='email' value={email} onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)} required></input><br></br>

            <label >Address: </label>
            <input type='text' value={address} onChange={(e) => setAddress(e.target.value)} required></input><br></br>

            <label >Username: </label>
            <input type='text' value={username} onChange={(e) => setUsername(e.target.value)} required></input><br/>

            <label >Password: </label>
            <input type='password' value={password} onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)} required></input>

            <input type='submit'></input>
        </form>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Register
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem with a different approach:

```
userId:auth.currentUser.uid,
```